# Transferring files to someone else via sftp

Tags: scp, sftp, file-transfer

Someone else is giving me a dataset that is too large to send via email, Dropbox, etc., so I'm thinking we can use sftp or scp. But how will she be able to do this without my giving her the password to my machine? This is a one-time transfer of data, so I'd rather not go through a lot of trouble -- if it's too much work I'll just give her my password and then change it when she's done transferring the files.

Comment: Are these both unix machines?

Comment: Yes, both are OS X

Comment: https://xkcd.com/949/

Comment: If you trust her with your data, you could make a passwordless login with ssh, then let her send you her public key and you could add it to your authorized keys file. For more security (and keeping your data enclosed) make her an account and do the same thing - just make sure your users' directory is closed for reading.

Comment: I just found a nice thing [here](http://cybermashup.com/2013/05/14/restrict-ssh-logins-to-a-single-command/) but haven't tried. I'd be interested if you could figure it out.

Comment: I don't know, but setting SFTP server with new chrooted user is both safe and must have millions results when you search for that. And it *should* work even on Mac, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Is your machine accessible over the Internet?

The first hurdle is that your machine may not be accessible over the Internet at all!

Most client machines cannot be accessed directly over the Internet because they don't have a public IP address. It's like having a phone that can call out, but can't be called. This came about mainly because there's a limited supply of IP addresses; unless your ISP supports IPv6 or you have a very atypical configuration, you have a single IP address at home, and that's the address of your home router. Your computers can make outgoing connections because the home router provides [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) functionality.

Most home routers can be configured to allow incoming connections to be routed to a particular machine on the local network. To allow incoming SSH connections, route port 22 to your computer. See your router's documentation for how to do this.

If you're unlucky and your ISP doesn't give a public IP address, you won't be able to make incoming connections. To check whether you have a public IP address, connect to your router's administrative interface and check whether its *external* address is in the [private range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses) (internal addresses are in the private range except in atypical configurations).

### Giving shell or file access to your machine

The (relatively) easy way to give someone access to your machine is to create a user account for them. With an ordinary user account, they'll be able to see a lot of things, but they won't be able to modify your files (unless you went out of your way to make them world-writable), and they won't be able to see the files that are in a private directory (`drwx------` permissions).

For better security, configure the account to be usable only to manipulate files in a particular directory over SFTP. This is a bit more difficult (I kind of expected OSX to provide an easy-to-use GUI for that, but apparently not); see [Create a remote only user in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41652/create-a-remote-only-user-in-os-x) or [How to set up an SFTP server on a Mac & then enable a friend to upload files to it from their iPhone, iPad, or other iDevice](http://www.chainsawonatireswing.com/2012/08/09/how-to-set-up-an-sftp-server-on-a-mac-then-enable-a-friend-to-upload-files-to-it-from-their-iphone-ipad-or-other-idevice) for instructions.

You'll need to enable remote access. There is an [OSX knowledge base entry](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18726?locale=en_US) for that. Enable only the one user who is supposed to have remote access. Do not enable remote access for an account that may have a weak password!

Set a random password on the account and tell them to copy-paste it and save it in a file. Don't expose a machine with weak, human-chosen passwords to the Internet. You can use the following command to generate the password:

```
</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 16; echo
```

### Transfering files piece by piece

So yeah, sending files over the Internet is still difficult.

[image: File Transfer]

The low-tech solution is to use one of the many file sharing websites. They make their money through ads, so don't even think of visiting one without an ad blocker, and be very careful where you click because they're likely to try to serve you malware. After downloading a file, check that it's the right file: calculate its SHA-2 checksum with

```
sha -a256 /path/to/file
```

on OSX, `sha256sum /path/to/file` on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind them having shell access to a different user on your system then you can just create a new user and give them the credentials. If you do then after creating the user you will need to configure your system to start SFTP in a chroot.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of complicating factors in doing this properly. The first, is that the receiver will need to open a NAT Forwarding port for SSH on your router/firewall/NAT Gateway, so that it's accessible from the internet.

The next is that `scp` and `sftp` work over an `ssh` session, and thus, she will need login credentials for an account on your system. If you give away the password to your user account, they'll be able to access anything on the system that your account has permissions for. Therefore, I would recommend creating a separate system account on the receiver system for `scp`/`sftp` only.

Once you create this separate account, you can force it to only allow `scp` using the [`scponly`](https://github.com/scponly/scponly) tool. Then you can either set a password for the new user account and provide it to the sender, or [use SSH keys](http://www.howtogeek.com/66776/how-to-remotely-copy-files-over-ssh-without-entering-your-password/) to avoid needing to enter a password.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time file transfer you can use woos (web offer one stream):

http://fex.belwue.de/fstools/woos.html

If you have to send or receive BIG files more often you should look at F*EX:

https://fex.rus.uni-stuttgart.de/